# How a guard can be implemented to a graphql resolver

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, graphql

I'm new in graphql and I am trying to integrate an authentication/authorization system in my project. I found an example on Medium, but I do not understand how a guard communicates with a resolver. If someone knows, I will be very grateful.

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { tradeTokenForUser } from './auth-helpers';

const HEADER_NAME = 'authorization';

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
     me: User
     serverTime: String
  }
  type User {
     id: ID!
     username: String!
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
   Query: {
      me: authenticated((root, args, context) => context.currentUser), 
      serverTime: () => new Date(),
   },
   User: {
      id: user => user._id,
      username: user => user.username,
   },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
   typeDefs,
   resolvers,
   context: async ({ req }) => {
      let authToken = null;
      let currentUser = null;

       try {
          authToken = req.headers[HEADER_NAME];

          if (authToken) {
               currentUser = await tradeTokenForUser(authToken);
          }
       } catch (e) {
          console.warn(`Unable to authenticate using auth token: ${authToken}`);
       }

      return {
          authToken,
          currentUser,
      };
   },
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

```
export const authenticated = next => (root, args, context, info) => {
  if (!context.currentUser) {
      throw new Error(`Unauthenticated!`);
  }

  return next(root, args, context, info);
};
```

I do not understand what "next" parameter does and why as an argument when this guard is called I have to return a value?

Answer (score 2):

`authenticated` is higher-order function that makes the code DRY. `next` is a callback that is used as a predicate.

It's a DRYer way to write:

```
...
me: (root, args, context) => {
  if (!context.currentUser) {
      throw new Error(`Unauthenticated!`);
  }

  return context.currentUser;
)
...
```